# autolayout both containers in the same size

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I want to create autolayout with two containers with the same size.

When user runs in 3.5 display i want containers have the same size. How to set up constraints? I have this 4 little containers in bottom: this is containers with pin height.

In this two big ones is only standard constraints. I don't really know how to set up containers for this.

[image: 4 inch display]

[image: 3.5 inch display]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Select both of your container views (by clicking on one, then command-clicking on the other).
- From the pinning menu (the girder-like one in the floating menu bar, or Editor --> Pin in XCode's menu bar) choose pin heights equally

All things being well, this should update the heights of your views and remove any unwanted system constraints (like the one pinning your lower container to the top of its superview). Switching between the 4 and 3.5 inch views should update automatically.